# How do I validate two input fields on HTML form?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have two inputs, one will be name and the other is module code.
How can I display an error message on either inputs if the pattern is wrong for either fields or if one field is empty?
Pretty sure something is wrong with my if-else statement ://
When I click submit, the form action will be activated.
Appreciate all help :)

```js
function validateForm() {
  var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  if (/^[A-Z]\D{2,30}$/.test(fname) == false) {
  //if its true, it will go to the second input
    document.getElementById("errorName").innerHTML = "Wrong format";
    fname.style.color="red";
    return false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("errorName").innerHTML = "";
  }
    
  var mcode = document.getElementById("mcode").value;
  if (/^[a-z]{3}[1-9]\d{4}$/.test(mcode) == false) {
    document.getElementById("errorCode").innerHTML = "Wrong format";
    mcode.style.color="red";
    return false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("errorCode").innerHTML = "";
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<form action="handleServer.php" method="get" onSubmit="return validateForm()">
  First name: </br>
  <input id="fname" type="text" name="fname" size="30"> 
  <span id="errorName" class="error"></br> 
  
  <!-- module code -->
  Module code: </br>
  <input id="mcode" type="text" name="mcode" size="30"> 
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  <span id="errorCode" class="error"></br>
```

Comment: What's wrong at the moment?

Comment: Your form element doesn't seem to have a closing tag. Is that a copy-paste error when pasting the code here?

Comment: Note that the HTML shown is invalid; `</br>` is an invalid construction: `<br>` is appropriate and valid; `<br/>` is allowed, but unnecessary. The code is missing a number of closing elements that are required, like `</span>` and `</form>`.

Comment: @iAmOren Is there a reason you rolled back the edit? The highlighter by default is using its JavaScript parser, and the edit changed it to use its HTML parser, which was more useful given the code is HTML...

Comment: @HereticMonkey, the edit was a mess and it was simpler to rollback than to fix the edit.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, had to re-do it: all those **** tabs from copy-paste into proper spaces...

Comment: + questions should not be ALL italics - no matter how "cute" it might seem.
* nor ALL bold, caps, underline, etc.

Comment: @iAmOren Okay. I think adding the Snippet was a positive. I don't think you needed to rollback anything to get there. You can click the Tidy button in the Snippet interface and it resolves tabs to spaces, if I'm not mistaken. Potayto Potahto- the post is in good shape now. Thanks for editing!

Comment: @HereticMonkey, I didn't know about the Tidy thing doing that - I'll try it next time someone is messy.

Comment: @Fuzzy hi! yes sorry i forgot to paste the </form>, thanks for letting me know I missed out on some closing tags! Ive added it in :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this to check whether the input fields are empty

```
function validateForm() {
    var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    var mcode = document.getElementById("mcode").value;
    var errorName = document.getElementById("errorName");
    var errorCode = document.getElementById("errorCode");

    if (fname === '') {
        errorName.innerHTML = "fname empty";
        return false;
    }
    if (mcode === '') {
        errorCode.innerHTML = "mcode empty";
        return false;
    }
    if (/^[A-Z]\D{2,30}$/.test(fname) == false) //if its true, it will go to the second input 
    {
        errorName.innerHTML = "Wrong format";
        fname.style.color = "red";
        return false;
    } else {
        errorName.innerHTML = "";
    }

    if (/^[a-z]{3}[1-9]\d{4}$/.test(mcode) == false) {
        errorCode.innerHTML = "Wrong format";
        mcode.style.color = "red";
        return false;
    } else {
        errorCode.innerHTML = "";
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for commenting! will try your method, however, I am also trying to understand what went wrong for mine!

Comment: Hi! ive tried it, it works for empty inputs but when I key in wrong formats for both inputs, the error message does display but my form gets submitted, meaning it goes to another url. I wonder is there something wrong with my form action? :/